# SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following script:

```
function getMoods(nb) {
    var index;
    var a = ["Banana", "Coconut", "Peach", "Apple", ...];
    for (index=0; index<nb; ++index) {
        alert('a');
        if(index==1 || index==5 || index==9 || index==13) { moods += '<div class="col-xs-4">'; }
            moods += '
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label for="'+a[index]+'">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="'+a[index]+'" class="moods"> '+a[index]+'
                    </label>
                </div>';
        if(index==4 || index==8 || index==12) { moods += '</div> '; }
    }
    $("#moods-area").html(moods);
}
```

I do not understand why I have the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF
```

Could you please help me ?

Comment: Javascript doesn't support multiline strings

Comment: extension to @Oriol: use '+(NEWLINE)'...

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems:

1. A wrong use of the [spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

   ```
   ["Banana", "Coconut", "Peach", "Apple", ...];
   ```

   This throws `SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']'`, because after the spread operator there isn't any iterable object.
2. JavaScript doesn't support multiline strings.

   You can use some alternatives:

   - Concatenate multiple strings

     ```
     moods += 
       '<div class="checkbox">'
         +'<label for="'+a[index]+'">'
           +'<input type="checkbox" id="'+a[index]+'" class="moods"> '+a[index]
         +'</label>'
       +'</div>';
     ```
   - Use `\` at the end of each line to continue the string at the next one

     ```
     moods += '\
       <div class="checkbox">\
         <label for="'+a[index]+'">\
           <input type="checkbox" id="'+a[index]+'" class="moods"> '+a[index]+'\
         </label>\
       </div>';
     ```
   - Join an array of strings:

     ```
     moods += [
       '<div class="checkbox">',
         '<label for="'+a[index]+'">',
           '<input type="checkbox" id="'+a[index]+'" class="moods"> '+a[index],
         '</label>',
       '</div>'].join('');
     ```

Comment: Thanks any idea why I have `object HTMLInputElement` in my page after ?