# extract IP on large text using AppleScript / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, applescript, extract, text-extraction

I'm try to selecting a large text and extract all the IP from this text.
E.g

> fdsfsfsdfsd   36.23.227.234   Paris,FR        FKGNGH  2df2df5cdsss    12151281250         November
>   23d, 2014 November 23d,
>   2014              titlethere      6928699 dfgdfgdfg   REWG50  US$50.00
>   fdsfddfseed   96.8.225.128    London,UK       FDGSDS  ASDGSDG22GDS    33583855464         January
>   30d, 2011 January 30d, 2011               titlethere      34576874    dsfasdg
>     ASASDF41    US€0.00

the result would be 36.23.227.234 96.8.225.128

Is this possible ? as the data is very random ? can AppleScript or maybe more javascript I'm guessing can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function in JavaScript:

```
var str = 'fdsfsfsdfsd 36.23.227.234 Paris,FR FKGNGH 2df2df5cdsss 12151281250 November 23d, 2014 November 23d, 2014 titlethere 6928699 dfgdfgdfg REWG50 US$50.00 fdsfddfseed 96.8.225.128 London,UK FDGSDS ASDGSDG22GDS 33583855464 January 30d, 2011 January 30d, 2011 titlethere 34576874 dsfasdg ASASDF41 US€0.00';
var regexp = /\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/gi;
var matches_array = str.match(regexp);
console.log(matches_array);
```

Which gives you Array [ "36.23.227.234", "96.8.225.128" ]

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41610014 for all occurences of a string and https://stackoverflow.com/a/32689475 for regex to find IP addresses.

Comment: Thank, that seems to work well with the demo line I wrote, but when I try in live with large data I have this "Error on line 1: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF"

Comment: Looks like an error because of the data being over multiple lines (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26325623/1619146). I guess I massaged your test data to remove this.
You could add a backslash (\) to each new line to keep everything in one string. This will take some manual work or maybe you can do it from where you output your data?

Comment: Thank you, yes I will find a way to add a backslash some how, thank you.